# Hiding text navigation when navigation close

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Here i create a navigation but when you click on the navigation '+' all the links show up right away and i want them to be shown syncronized with the animation.

Here is the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/6xVNz/3/

The jquery code:

```
$("#open").click(function(){
    $(".nav, #close").show();
   $(".nav li").show();
    $(".nav li").each(function (i) {
        $(this).delay(50*i).animate({width:150},50); // Change 300 to something else if you like
    });
    $("#open").hide();
});

$("#close").click(function(){
    $("#close").hide();
        $($(".nav li").get().reverse()).each(function (i) {
            $(this).delay(50*i).animate({width:0},50); // Change 300 to something else if you like
    });
    $("#open").show();
});
```

Comment: you want start view after closing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change your code like this :

```
 $("#open").click(function(){
    $(".nav, #close").show();
   $(".nav li").show();
    $(".nav li").each(function (i) {
        $(this).delay(50*i).animate({width:150},50); // Change 300 to something else if you like
    });
    $("#open").hide();
});

$("#close").click(function(){
    $("#close").hide();
        $($(".nav li").get().reverse()).each(function (i) {
            $(this).delay(50*i).animate({width:0},50); // Change 300 to something else if you like
    });
    $("#open").show();
    $(".nav li").hide('slow');
});
```

Comment: it's effecting the close animation

Comment: i  mean that now when u close the nav there is no animation before this change it was

Comment: the nav links was closing one by one

Comment: and now they are all closing in boom without any animation

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#open").click(function(){
    $(".nav, #close").show();
   $(".nav li").show();
    $(".nav li").each(function (i) {
        $(this).delay(50*i).animate({width:150},50); // Change 300 to something else if you like
    });
    $("#open").hide();
});

$("#close").click(function(){
    $("#close").hide();
        $($(".nav li").get().reverse()).each(function (i) {
            $(this).delay(50*i).animate({width:0},50); // Change 300 to something else if you like
    });
    $("#open").show();
    $(".nav li").hide('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$("#open").click(function(){
    $(".nav, #close").show();

    $(".nav li").each(function (i) {
        $(this).delay(50*i).animate({width:150},50).show(50); 
    });
    $("#open").hide();
});

$("#close").click(function(){
    $("#close").hide();
    $($(".nav li").get().reverse()).each(function (i) {
        $(this).delay(50*i).animate({width:0},50).hide(50); 
    });
    $("#open").show();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6xVNz/11/)

Comment: can you explain how u did it?

Comment: In the first `each` function I made the links become visible in the browser one by one with `show(50)`(make sure the value is the same as the width animation value for the effect you wanted). In the second I instead made them invisible in the browser one by one. Sorry that that bug was in my answer on you previous question! :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#open").click(function(){
    $(".nav, #close").show();
   $(".nav li").show();
    $(".nav li").each(function (i) {
        $(this).delay(50*i).animate({width: "150px"},800); // Change 300 to something else if you like
    });
    $("#open").hide();
});

$("#close").click(function(){
    $("#close").hide();
        $($(".nav li").get().reverse()).each(function (i) {
            $(this).delay(50*i).animate({width: "0px"},800); // Change 300 to something else if you like
    });
    $("#open").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this if this works for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/6xVNz/9/

What i understand from your question is you want the menus to come one by one in synchronization.

```
$("#open").click(function(){
    $(".nav, #close").show();
    //$(".nav li").show();
    $(".nav li").each(function (i) {
        //alert(i);
        $(this).delay(300*i).animate({width:150},50).show(); // Change 300 to something else if you like
        //$(".nav li").show();
    });
    $("#open").hide();
});

$("#close").click(function(){
    $("#close").hide();
        $($(".nav li").get().reverse()).each(function (i) {
            $(this).delay(50*i).animate({width:0},50); // Change 300 to something else if you like
    });
    $("#open").show();
});
```